# Issue with LocationListener Network_provider in android

Tags: android, networking, provider, locationlistener

I have an app that implements LocationListener using Network_Provider and onLocationChanged(), I am logging the new location in a log file with timestamp. This app is run as a service.

I am seeing unusual behavior with this :

1. it seems to be capturing location from a wi-fi location only ( no cellular network provider )
2. once the service is started, it waits till it finds the first wi-fi location. Until then it does not log anything.
3. once it finds the location thru wi-fi, it starts logging the location latitude/longitude
4. this logging continues thereafter, every 45sec, eventhough the location is not changed ..
5. this logging continues thereafter, every 45 sec, eventhough the device is moved out of range of that wi-fi, in fact, from my home to work @ 20 miles (no wi-fi at work)  and it still continues to log the same location every 45 sec .

wierd ?

Here is my code :

```
public class TestLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager lm;
    public TestLocationService() {
     }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String loc= "Time : "+new Date()+"\n";
        loc += "New Location "+location.getLatitude()+" and "+location.getLongitude()+"\n*******************\n";
        System.out.println(loc);
          try {
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/loc");
                dir.mkdirs();
                File file = new File(dir, "loc.txt");
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);  
                osw.write(loc);
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();                
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
     public void onCreate() {
        this.lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }


}
```

-abhay

Comment: Thanks @frayab ! added my code to the main question above.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer.
About point 1: Do you want capturing location from a wi-fi location only? Or your desire is capture with best provider?
About point 2: If you tell only network provider is logic that it waits till it finds the first wi-fi location.
About point 4: I think that is the normal behavior of location listener in Android.
About point 5: If you want stop receiving coordinates when provider if out of range, you have to fill onProviderDisabled method and call to lm.removeUpdates(this);

Comment: I would like to use best provider .. but question is , even with NETWORK_PROVIDER, why does the cellphone network provider e.g. AT&T or T-Mobile doesn't provide location updates. It is only receiving the Wi-Fi location updates. Since I am always connected to the cell phone network, I should always have a current location.

Comment: if you use network_provider you will only receive WIFI location updates.

Comment: What do I need to do to receive location updates from cell phone service provide, like AT&T in US and IDEA in india ?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

by:

```
this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(this.lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(),true),0,0,this);
```

In this case your phone will use the best enabled provider